# I am making a physics simulator with pygame/python. I have a Menu issue

Tags: python, pygame

My PhysicsSim program is the main menu from which I import all the other modules after the specific buttons on the menu have been clicked. My issue is that when I 'click' the button and launch the program, and then close it (via the close window button) I cannot reopen the program. All my modules have booleans for the while running loops. Here is my code for PhysicsSim (main menu).

```
import pygame, sys
import projectile_mechanics
import Pendulum
import main2

exitpressed = False


class ButtonExit:
    def __init__(self,text,width,height,pos,elevation, exitpressed):
        #Core attributes 
        self.pressed = False
        self.elevation = elevation
        self.dynamic_elecation = elevation
        self.original_y_pos = pos[1]

        # top rectangle 
        self.top_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.top_color = '#475F77'

        # bottom rectangle 
        self.bottom_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.bottom_color = '#354B5E'
        #text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text,True,'#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center = self.top_rect.center)

    def draw(self):
        # elevation logic 
        self.top_rect.y = self.original_y_pos - self.dynamic_elecation
        self.text_rect.center = self.top_rect.center 

        self.bottom_rect.midtop = self.top_rect.midtop
        self.bottom_rect.height = self.top_rect.height + self.dynamic_elecation

        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.bottom_color, self.bottom_rect,border_radius = 12)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.top_color, self.top_rect,border_radius = 12)
        screen1.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        self.check_click()
    
    def check_click(self):
        global exitpressed
        exitpressed = False
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.top_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.top_color = '#D74B4B'
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.dynamic_elecation = 0
                self.pressed = True
                exitpressed = True
                
            
            else:
                self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
                if self.pressed == True:
                    
                    self.pressed = False
                    
        else:
            self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
            self.top_color = '#475F77'


class Button3:
    def __init__(self,text,width,height,pos,elevation):
        #Core attributes 
        
        self.pressed = False
        self.elevation = elevation
        self.dynamic_elecation = elevation
        self.original_y_pos = pos[1]

        # top rectangle 
        self.top_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.top_color = '#475F77'

        # bottom rectangle 
        self.bottom_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.bottom_color = '#354B5E'
        #text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text,True,'#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center = self.top_rect.center)

    def draw(self):
        # elevation logic 
        self.top_rect.y = self.original_y_pos - self.dynamic_elecation
        self.text_rect.center = self.top_rect.center 

        self.bottom_rect.midtop = self.top_rect.midtop
        self.bottom_rect.height = self.top_rect.height + self.dynamic_elecation

        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.bottom_color, self.bottom_rect,border_radius = 12)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.top_color, self.top_rect,border_radius = 12)
        screen1.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        self.check_click()
    
    def check_click(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.top_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.top_color = '#D74B4B'
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.dynamic_elecation = 0
                self.pressed = True
                main2.runorbit()
                
            else:
                self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
                if self.pressed == True:
                    
                    self.pressed = False
                    
        else:
            self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
            self.top_color = '#475F77'


class Button2:
    
    def __init__(self,text,width,height,pos,elevation):
        #Core attributes 
        self.pressed = False
        self.elevation = elevation
        self.dynamic_elecation = elevation
        self.original_y_pos = pos[1]

        # top rectangle 
        self.top_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.top_color = '#475F77'

        # bottom rectangle 
        self.bottom_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.bottom_color = '#354B5E'
        #text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text,True,'#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center = self.top_rect.center)

    def draw(self):
        # elevation logic 
        self.top_rect.y = self.original_y_pos - self.dynamic_elecation
        self.text_rect.center = self.top_rect.center 

        self.bottom_rect.midtop = self.top_rect.midtop
        self.bottom_rect.height = self.top_rect.height + self.dynamic_elecation

        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.bottom_color, self.bottom_rect,border_radius = 12)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.top_color, self.top_rect,border_radius = 12)
        screen1.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        self.check_click()
    
    def check_click(self):
        
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.top_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.top_color = '#D74B4B'
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.dynamic_elecation = 0
                self.pressed = True
                #import projectile_mechanics
                projectile_mechanics.runproj()
                
            
            else:
                self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
                if self.pressed == True:
                    self.pressed = False
        else:
            self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
            self.top_color = '#475F77'
    

class Button:
    def __init__(self,text,width,height,pos,elevation):
        #Core attributes 
        self.pressed = False
        self.elevation = elevation
        self.dynamic_elecation = elevation
        self.original_y_pos = pos[1]

        # top rectangle 
        self.top_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.top_color = '#475F77'

        # bottom rectangle 
        self.bottom_rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(width,height))
        self.bottom_color = '#354B5E'
        #text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text,True,'#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center = self.top_rect.center)

    def draw(self):
        # elevation logic 
        self.top_rect.y = self.original_y_pos - self.dynamic_elecation
        self.text_rect.center = self.top_rect.center 

        self.bottom_rect.midtop = self.top_rect.midtop
        self.bottom_rect.height = self.top_rect.height + self.dynamic_elecation

        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.bottom_color, self.bottom_rect,border_radius = 12)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen1,self.top_color, self.top_rect,border_radius = 12)
        screen1.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        self.check_click()

    def check_click(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.top_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.top_color = '#D74B4B'
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.dynamic_elecation = 0
                self.pressed = True
                
                #import Pendulum
                Pendulum.runpend()
                
                
                
            else:
                self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
                if self.pressed == True:
                    
                    self.pressed = False
        else:
            self.dynamic_elecation = self.elevation
            self.top_color = '#475F77'

pygame.init()
screen1 = pygame.display.set_mode((1216,700), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('PhysicsSim')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gui_font = pygame.font.Font(None,24)
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)

def title():
    text = font1.render("Physics Simulation", True, (0,0,0))
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(((screen1.get_width())/2), ((screen1.get_height())/(20/3))))
    screen1.blit(text, text_rect)

#button1 = Button('Pendulum',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(5/2))))),5)
#button2 = Button2('Projectiles',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/27))))),5) 
#button3 = Button3('Orbits',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/34))))),5)
#button4 = ButtonExit('Exit',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/41))))),5, False)
    
#def DefineButtons():   
    #global button1, button2, button3, button4
    #button1 = Button('Pendulum',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(5/2))))),5)
    #button2 = Button2('Projectiles',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/27))))),5) 
    #button3 = Button3('Orbits',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/34))))),5)
    #button4 = ButtonExit('Exit',100,50,((((screen1.get_width())/2)-50),(((screen1.get_height()/(50/41))))),5, False)   
    
    
button1 = Button('Pendulum',100,50,(558,200),5)
button2 = Button2('Projectiles',100,50,(558,270),5) 
button3 = Button3('Orbits',100,50,(558,340),5)
button4 = ButtonExit('Exit',100,50,(558,410),5, False)

while exitpressed == False:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #pygame.quit()
            exitpressed == True
            
    screen1.fill('#DCDDD8')
    title()
    
    #DefineButtons()
    
    button1.draw()
        
    button2.draw()
        
    button3.draw()
        
    button4.draw()  

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Pendulum Module Code:

```
import pygame, sys

import math 

  

#VARIABLES 

width, height = 800, 500   # set the width and height of the window 
exitpressed1 = False

                           # (you can increase or decrease if you want to, just remind to keep even numbers) 

Out = False                # if True,out of while loop, and close pygame 

acceleration = False       # when true it allow us to find the acceleration and damping for the pendulum 

length = 0                 # the length between the ball and the support 

angle = 0                  # the angle that you begin when click in window 

vel = 0                    # velocity that angle is increased and damped 

Aacc = 0   

              # acceleration 

  

#COLORS 

white = (255,255,255) 

black = (0,0,0) 

gray = (150, 150, 150) 

Dark_red = (150, 0, 0) 

  

#BEFORE START 

#pygame.init()


background = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) 

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

  

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25) 

class ball(object): 

     

    def __init__(self, XY, radius):  # Set ball coordenates and radius 

        self.x = XY[0] 

        self.y = XY[1] 

        self.radius = radius 

  

    def draw(self, bg):  # Draw circle and line based on XY coordinates 

        pygame.draw.lines(bg, black, False, [(width/2, 50), (self.x, self.y)], 2) 

        pygame.draw.circle(bg, black, (self.x, self.y), self.radius) 

        pygame.draw.circle(bg, Dark_red, (self.x, self.y), self.radius - 2) 

  

  

def grid():  # Draw a grid behind the pendulum 

    for x in range(50, width, 50): 

        pygame.draw.lines(background, gray, False, [(x, 0), (x, height)]) 

        for y in range(50, height, 50): 

            pygame.draw.lines(background, gray, False, [(0, y), (width, y)]) 

    pygame.draw.circle(background, black, (int(width/2), 50), 5) 

  

def angle_Length():  # Send back the length and angle at the first click on screen 

    length = math.sqrt(math.pow(pendulum.x - width/2, 2) + math.pow(pendulum.y - 50, 2)) 

    angle = math.asin((pendulum.x - width/2)/ length) 

    return (angle, length) 

  

def get_path(first_angle, length): # with angle and length calculate x and y position 

    pendulum.x = round(width/2 + length * math.sin(angle)) 

    pendulum.y = round(50 + length * math.cos(angle)) 

     

  

def redraw(msg, msg2, color, color2): # Clean up the screen and start a new grid and new frame of pendulum with new coordinates 

    background.fill(white) 

    grid() 

    pendulum.draw(background) 

     
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color) 
    screen_text2 = font.render(msg2, True, color2) 

    background.blit(screen_text, [30,30]) 
    background.blit(screen_text2, [30, 60]) 
    

    pygame.display.update() 


pendulum = ball((int(width / 2),-100), 5) # I start the class with some random coordinates 




#not Out
while True: 

    clock.tick(120)             #Set how many frames are draw per second 

                                    #If changed, maybe, could be a good idea change some values at acceleration 

      

    for event in pygame.event.get():                     # 

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            #Out = True  
            import PhysicsSim 
            pygame.quit()                # 

                                                 # 

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:         #  Read if you want go out 

            pendulum = ball(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), 15)  #             or 

            angle, length = angle_Length()               #   click the mouse button 

            acceleration = True  
                
                                      

      

    if acceleration:   # Increase acceleration and damping in the pendulum moviment 

        Aacc = -0.005 * math.sin(angle) 

        vel += Aacc 
            

        vel *= 0.994  # damping factor 

        angle += vel 

        angleD = angle * (180/(math.pi)) 

        get_path(angle, length) 
            
        
    

         

  

    redraw("Angle: " + str(round(abs(angle * (180/(math.pi))),1)) + " degrees.", "String Length: " + str(math.trunc(abs(length))) + " pixels.", black, black) 
  
    
   

  

#pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I can also link an example module code if needed

Comment: Which button are you talking about?  When you say "launch the program", do you mean double-clicking a desktop icon, or do you mean something in the code here?  If your other modules have loops, how do they exit?

Comment: Launch programs as in clicking the button I have displayed on the screen, and exit program as in pressing the windows close button to quit the specific program window.

Comment: Well, we can't really go much deeper without the source for the modules.

Comment: will update the code

Comment: Both of those files think they are in charge.  Both of them are running `pygame.init`.  You need to reorganize your code so that one file is the "master" -- it initializes `pygame` and runs the event loop, and the other files are just offering services to that main file.

Comment: So don't initialize pygame within each module, but still import it so the code actually works?

Comment: Yes.  You need to `import pygame` so the modules have access to the functions and constants.  `pygame-init()` is a run-time thing that only needs to be run once in the app.

Comment: okay and you suggested I use functions for each module and import the modules as well as call their functions off button click. Should my pygame.init() be somewhere else in the PhysicsSim program. I had an issue earlier where the modules would launch before the menu because of the way I was importing them I assume.

Comment: You just have to call `pygame.init()` some time before you start using pygame.  That's just telling it to get ready to do stuff.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: OK and also adjust code to use a function for each module

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how `import` works.  If the module had already been imported, running `import` again does absolutely nothing.  This is why we always put `import` statements at the top of the file.

In your secondary files, you need to put the code into a function.  Then, put

```
import main2
import projectile_mechanics
import Pendulum
```

at the top, and in your code do:

```
        main2.main()
...
        projectile_mechanics.projectile_mechanics()
...
        Pendulum.swing_penduluum()
```

Or, alternatively:

```
from main2 import main
from projectile_mechanics import projectile_mechanics
from Pendulum import swing_pendulum
```

I have, of course, invented the function names.  You should choose your own that make sense.

Comment: OK so for each module just have a running function for the full code and then call that function when the button is clicked?

Comment: That just runs the modules directly off import. If I import Pendulum and then call the function from the module on the click activation

Comment: Right.  It's exactly the way standard modules work.   You import `pygame`, which makes a bunch of handy functions available to you.  When you need them, you call `pygame.init()`.  Exactly the same concept.

Comment: ok so if I do that I can now launch each program two times and then it wont allow me to launch them anymore. I will update the main code above. I will also put the error message it is giving me.